# Resize/rotate image from Nemo (Ubuntu 18.10)

Tags: resize, nemo, rotate

I cannot find a way to install the right-click resize/rotate from Nemo (3.8.5) file explorer, on Ubuntu 18.10 Gnome Shell

Tried solution:
- install .deb from https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/mint_main/rosa/main/base/nemo-image-converter

Comment: hi! so `sudo apt install nemo-image-converter` does not work? could you update your post to include what you **have** tried so far?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10: sudo apt install nemo-image-converter   
E: Unable to locate package nemo-image-converter

Answer (score 1):

so your link has this : 
[image: link says from mint ppa]

from the same website : https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/mint_main :

```
sudo apt-get install linuxmint-keyring
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ tara main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mint.list' 
sudo apt update
```

run the .deb again or

```
sudo apt install nemo-image-converter
```

Comment: That did it to install nemo-image-converter but the contextual menu doesnt appear in Nemo 3.8.5

Comment: ah unfortunate. must be incompatible. hopefully they'll fix it. you should report this as a bug to the nemo-image-converter people

Comment: It didn't show up for me until I restarted nemo. `nemo -q` and then open nemo again.